# How to use float and margin together?

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin

How could I remove this extra space middle of "Top content" and "Left content" ?

I want Left and Right to the same level.

I don't want to lose equal margin for all these blocks.

**STATIC IMAGE**

[image: Example image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="top">Top content</div>
<div class="left">Left content</div>
<div class="right">Right content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top
{
    margin: 3%;
    background: red;
}

.left
{
    margin: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
}

.right
{
    margin: 3%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
}
```

**LIVE DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/20/

**BEST SOLUTION SO FAR**

http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/14/

If we could use same margin with Top content, then this solution would be perfect.

Comment: Float `.right`.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/yF6MX/1/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
.top
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: red;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;

}

.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
}

.right
{  
    background: green;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You were doing great, but with you "margin:10px" in .top, you were adding a margin on your left block, just do margin on left and right

Comment: This is best solution so far. Is it really impossible to use same margin with .top ? Here's live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/14/

Comment: Hey, I think I got what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/24/

In fact look at your code, these are your mistakes:
you didn't position .right in float:right, so it didn't know where to go compared to .left.
Then, you were doing width:50% with your .left, but you had 3% margin left and right, so in fact your .left was 50+3+3% = 56%.
You have to say that your .left is 50-3-3=44% and your .right is 44% too. then you can have margin:3% everywhere ;-)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the margin-top from your left and right elements.

```
margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/5/

Comment: I want to use margin's overlap. Your solution works, but I would like to have margin: 10px or margin: 3%.

Answer (score 0):

use this

**UPDATE** http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/15/

```
    .top
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 47%;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 2%;
}

.right
{  
    background: green;
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 47%;
}
```

Comment: Margin isn't even with this solution. There's more margin between Left and Right, than Left and Top or Right and Top.

Comment: Thanks, but too hacky for my taste, this is best so far: http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/14/

Comment: I could live with that. More important with this case is equal margin and usage of margin's overlap. In ideal world equal left and right (50% and 50%) would be awesome, but we can't have both?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally add a `container` with `padding` all around it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">Top content</div>
    <div class="left">Left content</div>
    <div class="right">Right content</div>
</div>
```

Then remove the other `margin` properties and stick a `margin-bottom` on `.top` and `margin-right` on `.left`, and also add the new `.container` `CSS`:

```
.container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.top {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #FF0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/yF6MX/16/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will do, but it's little bit too complicated, if compared to one margin solution (if it even exists).

Comment: Apologies, but this is the correct way to build `HTML`. Nothing complicated about it.

Comment: Margin between Left and Right is coming from width now and because we're using percents, it won't be equal if you scale window up. Otherwise nice one :)

Comment: @stacknoob Hence my original answer.

Comment: I prefer this http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/22/ 
before this http://jsfiddle.net/yF6MX/23/ 
Wouldn't say neither is wrong.